# What does the %# flag in a printf statement in C?

Tags: c, printf

I am doing the chapter 3 of the book learning C the hard way by Zed Shaw. I am exploring the different string formatting options for printf. I encountered the following flag to put after the '%#' symbol:

The value should be converted to an "alternate form". For o conversions, the first character of the output string is made zero (by prefixing a 0 if it was not zero already). For x and X conversions, a nonzero result has the string "0x" (or "0X" for X conversions) prepended to it. For a, A, e, E, f, F, g, and G conversions, the result will always contain a decimal point, even if no digits follow it (normally, a decimal point appears in the results of those conversions only if a digit follows). For g and G conversions, trailing zeros are not removed from the result as they would otherwise be. For other conversions, the result is undefined.

It seems that '%#' flag is for a kind of type conversion for the printf statement. But I am not sure. Does anyone knows what kind of conversion of actual usage this %# flag has in the printf function in C?  I can see any change or conversion for the character "A", which is the one I am using for the flag %# in the last print statement.

This is my code:

```
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int age = 32; // age and height not initialized
    int height = 182;
    printf("I am %d cm tall.\n", age); 
    printf("I am %d years old.\n", height); 
    printf("I wanna go to \"Panama\"\n"); // scaping double quotes 
    printf("I am %2$d tall and %1$d years old\n", age, height); // how to use positional arguments in printf statement
    // how to use positional arguments in printf statement  
    printf("I am using the number pi: %'.2f\n", 3.1415939);

    // Testing the %# formatting 
    printf("Testing for A: %# \n", 'A');
    return 0;
}
```

The output I receive:

```
I am 32 cm tall.
I am 182 years old.
I wanna go to "Panama"
I am 182 tall and 32 years old
I am using the number pi: 3.14
Testing for A: %#
```

Comment: `"%#"` on its own doesn't mean anything. The `#` is a *flag* that modifies the output of the format specifier (which you don't provide in your string). If the compiler doesn't warn you about this then you need to enable more warning (e.g. `-Wall` for `gcc`).

Comment: Also note that the `"%1$n"` (and the like) is not a standard C feature of [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). It's a POSIX extension and thus may not exist on other systems (like Windows using MSVC). And the `'` in e.g. `"%'.2f"` is also non-standard.

Comment: `%#` is not a flag. `#` is a flag. As for what it does, it's explained right there in the paragraph you quoted. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are providing a legal `#` flag, but you do not specify any legal conversion character (`idouxXsc` etc...). In that case, the behavior of printf is undefined.

Here a few (untested) examples:

```
printf("%#x\n", 17);
printf("%#X\n", 17);
printf("%#f\n", 1.42);
printf("%#A\n", 1.42);
```

**Reference:**

- See the [printf manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) for reference.
- `man 3 printf` checking the `man` on your system can help you to understand behaviors not defined by the C standard.

Comment: People should not use Linux `man` pages or `man` on their system without understanding they are specific to Linux or to their system and may contain behaviors not defined by the C standard, so that code written based on such documentation may not work in other C implementations. When you advise people to use `man` pages for C functions, it would be good to advise them of the difference.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: not only to Linux, some of them are written specifically for GLIBC